# Set a short value in constructor call

Tags: java, casting, primitive, short

I have an `enum` with a constructor:

```java
enum myEnum {
    A(0), B(1), C(2);

    private final short value;

    private myEnum(short value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public short getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, Eclipse is letting me know that there is no constructor accepting a single `int`. Therefore I am relegated to casting to a short...

```
A((short) 0), B((short) 1), C((short) 2);
```

...whether this is done for each value or taking an `int` in the constructor and casting at assignment.

Is there a better way to do this than taking the time to cast, or is there no better solution?

Comment: java whole number literals (`1`, `-234`, etc.) are always `int`s, so there is no way around casting

Comment: There is no literals for short values. You have to cast.

Comment: Why not just make a second constructor to take ints instead of shorts?
```private myEnum(int value) {
        this.value = (short) value;
    }```

Comment: why are you using shorts in the first place?

Comment: @Lino That's the answer I was afraid of, and what turned out to be the duplicate I just accepted. Thanks. (I'm using a `short` because of other pre-existing methods in the project.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
short shortValue = Integer.valueOf(0).shortValue();
```

Under the hood it's still the same. So it's kind to turn a blind eye on.

Answer (score -1):

You always have to cast, because unfortunately there is no literal format for shorts, what I suggest is to add another constructor to your enum:

```
private myEnum(int value) {
    this((short) value);
}
```

This way you will avoid casting it for the values of the enum.

Comment: This is bad. It could result in an overflow since `short` is way smaller than `int`.

Comment: @MuratK. you're right, but in this case I don't think that the overflow will take place, since the enum values are 'countable'

Comment: My question stated this as an option worse than casting each individual value. The values will be countable.